# How to install specific nvidia driver like nvidia-driver-440_440.33.01.deb?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, dependencies

This page https://developer.download.nvidia.cn/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/ list lots of drivers.

I need to install the version `nvidia-driver-440_440.33.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` because my `dmesg` is saying:

```
NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 440.33, but
NVRM: this kernel module has the version 440.100.  Please
NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
NVRM: components have the same version.
```

after I run

```
docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi
```

So I need the specific version `440.33`

I tried downloading and installing:

```
sudo apt install -y ./nvidia-driver-440_440.33.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-440' instead of './nvidia-driver-440_440.33.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-440 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-dkms-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1)
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-compute-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-440 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.8) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-440:i386 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-440:i386 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-440:i386 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-440:i386 (= 440.33.01-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) answer will help you resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like installing package manually will cause dependency issues and You might endup in breaking dependency tree.

I would suggest you to use official nvidia ubuntu ppa. It will install necessary dependencies automatically.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y 

 sudo apt update -y 

 sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440 -y
```

If you are using docker image for your application,You can re-build docker image with particular version to align with driver version. You can add above commands in docker file and build docker image.

Comment: The problem is that it'll install 440.100, but my program uses some cuda driver that uses 440.35.01

Comment: Please edit your question and add full details what original issue you have.

Comment: edited!............